# Jquery only running once on duplicate element

Tags: jquery

here: http://jsfiddle.net/gorelegacy/bn6Z2/

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $("#directions").click(function(e) {
        $("#map").slideToggle('fast');
    });
});
```

This is the code I'm working with above.

I have a simple slidetoggle on the 'get directions' text. But it only works on number 1. It then doesnt work for the 2nd and 3rd 'get directions'

Comment: Do you realize that an id value MUST be unique in the document?  You can only have one element with a given id.  When you refer to an id like `$("#directions")`, that is only ever going to find the first one with that id.  Use a `class="directions"` and then `$(".directions")` if you want to have more than one.

Comment: if i realised i wouldnt be posting here. Do you have a solution

Comment: You don't have to get snippety.  I'm just assessing your level of knowledge.  Read what else is in my comment above.

Comment: okay thanks. You edited your post. Thanks ill give it a go.
Im a rookie ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Changing my comment into an answer.

You can only have one element in a document with a given id so `$("#directions")` will only find the first item with that id.

If you want to have multiple items with an identifier, then you a class instead:

```
<div class="directions"></div>
```

And, then refer to the class in the jQuery:

```
$(".directions").click(...);
```

That will get all the elements with that class name.

---

If you also have more than one map, then you will have to also change that to a class and how you find the appropriate map object given the directions object that was clicked on depends upon your HTML structure.  You would need to share your HTML for us to advise on the best way to do that.  Usually, it involves using `$(this)` to reference the button that was clicked on, then a `.closest("some selector")` to go up the parent chain to a common parent, and then a `.find(".map")` to find the map object associated with that button, something like this:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="directions">Get Directions</div>
    <div class="map"></div>
</div>

$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".directions").click(function() {
        $(this).closest(".container").find(".map").slideToggle('fast');
    });
});
```

But, the exact code would depend upon your HTML.

Comment: thankyou. Have you done $(this).closest(".container") for performance?

Comment: @AdamG - I've done it for design flexibility.  It will find the `.map` within the same container even if the HTML layout is changed somewhat so it makes the code more robust.

Answer (score 1):

Since `id` must be unique, you need to use class instead for `directions` and `map`:

```
<div class="directions"><p>Get Directions</p></div>
<div class="map">
```

then you can use `.` to target elements by class:

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $(".directions").click(function(e) {
        $(this).next().slideToggle('fast');
    });
});
```

Please note that you also need to change your CSS by using `.` instead of `#` for `directions` and `map` to make it works as expected.

**[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bn6Z2/1/)**